# ¿Por qué (PHP/SQL) sólo puedo modificar el último registro en una base de datos?

Tags: php, sql

Es algo muy básico, quiero que el admin sea capaz de modificar el registro que quiera, pero sólo consigo modificar el último registro. ¿Alguna ayuda? ¿por qué solamente me permite actualizar el último?

Acceso admin:

```
<?php

include("datos.php");
include ("funciones.php");

$con=conectar ($host,$usuario,$clave,$base);

if (!$con){
    echo "error" ;
} else{

    if(($_POST["user"]=="admin" && $_POST["password"]=="admin")){

$user=$_POST["user"];
$password=$_POST["password"];
$C=0;
    $consulta= "SELECT * FROM usuarios  ";
    $paquete= consultar($con,$consulta);


     while ($fila=mysqli_fetch_array($paquete)) {
         if ($fila["user"]==$user && $fila["password"]==$password) {
                $C=$C+1 ;
}
}        

$consulta= "SELECT * FROM usuarios  ";
    $paquete= consultar($con,$consulta);


echo "<table border='1'>";
echo "<td><strong>Id</strong></td>";
echo "<td><strong>Usuario</strong></td>";
echo "<td><strong>Contraseña</strong></td>";

while ($fila=mysqli_fetch_array($paquete)){

    echo "<form action='modificar.php' method='post'>";

    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td><input type='text' name='id' value='" . $fila['id'] . "'></td>";
    echo "<td><input type='text' name='user' value='" . $fila['user'] . "'></td>" ;
    echo "<td><input type='text' name='password' value='" . $fila['password'] . "'></td>" ;
    echo "</tr>";
}

echo "</table>";

echo "<input type='submit' name='enviando' value='Modificar'><p>";

echo "</form>";  

   }
  }
?>
```

Modificar registro:

```
<?php

require("datos.php");

$id=$_POST["id"];
$user=$_POST["user"];
$password=$_POST["password"];


$conexion=mysqli_connect($host, $usuario, $clave, $base);

if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
    echo "fallo al conectar la BBDD";

    exit();

}

mysqli_select_db($conexion, $base) or die ("No se encuentra la BBDD");

$consulta="UPDATE usuarios SET user='$user', password='$password' WHERE id='$id'";

$resultados=mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta);

if($resultados==false){

    echo "Error al modificar registro";
}else{
    echo "Registro modificado";

}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Tu problema es que estas definiendo 'n' inputs con el mismo nombre (uno por cada iteracion del whilte) por lo que al enviar el formulario solo tendra en cuenta el último.

Aparte de eso tambien estas definiendo n formularios.

Basicamente lo que tu codigo genera es esto (he omitido las tablas)

```
<form action='modificar.php' method='post'>
<input type='text' name='id' value=''/>
<input type='text' name='user' value=''/>
<input type='text' name='password' value=''/>

<form action='modificar.php' method='post'>
<input type='text' name='id' value=''/>
<input type='text' name='user' value=''/>
<input type='text' name='password' value=''/>


<form action='modificar.php' method='post'>
<input type='text' name='id' value=''/>
<input type='text' name='user' value=''/>
<input type='text' name='password' value=''/>

......



<form action='modificar.php' method='post'>
<input type='text' name='id' value=''/>
<input type='text' name='user' value=''/>
<input type='text' name='password' value=''/>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda. Confirmas mis sospechas. Lamentablemente soy incapaz de solucionarlo.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer un archivo .php que tenga parámetros de get (archivo.php?id=5 por ejemplo)
y que en el form  esté  action="archivo.php?id=5" 
cosa que en el archivo.php?id=5 te modifique los datos del get del id